# Getting count per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently my query is resulting in the `[CountAccns]` field it is returning the monthly count but I need the daily count!

```
;with
cte_biggie ( [Full Date],     [Year Entered],   [Month Entered],  [Day Entered],      
[DOW],      [Week Ending] ,[CountAccns],[Sales Rep],   [MLNPI], [IMSNPI],     [Physician],      
[Practice Code],  [MLIS Code],      [Practice Name],  
[Date Established],     [Address],  [Address2], [City],     [State],    [Status]
) as (
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [DATE entered], 1),DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) ,  
CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01 THEN 'Jan' 
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 02 THEN 'Feb'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 03 THEN 'Mar'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 04 THEN 'Apr'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 05 THEN 'May'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 06 THEN 'Jun'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 07 THEN 'Jul'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 08 THEN 'Aug'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 09 THEN 'Sep'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 10 THEN 'Oct'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 11 THEN 'Nov'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 12 THEN 'Dec'
           END
           ,DATEPART(dd, [DATE entered]),

           case when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=1 THEN 'Sun'
           when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=2 THEN 'Mon'
           when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=3 THEN 'Tus'
           when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=4 THEN 'Wed'
           when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=5 THEN 'Thu'
           when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=6 THEN 'Fri'
           when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=7 THEN 'Sat'
           end,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD (D, -1 * DatePart (dw,[date entered]) + 6, [date entered]), 1),
            count(a.[specimen id]) ,c.salesrep,c.npi,e.npib,[Requesting Physician] ,
           a.[practice code],b.[mlis practice id],[practice name],

   c.dateestablished , c.practiceaddress1, c.practiceaddress2,c.practicecity,c.practicestate,
    b.[Active Inactive]
from quicklabdump a
    left outer join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[practice code] = a.[practice code])
    left outer join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
    and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
    left outer join TestResults d 
    on a.QuickLabDumpID = d.QuickLabDumpID
    left outer join IMSData e
    on c.NPI=e.npib
where    [Date Entered] <= '20111231'
and [Date Entered] >= '20111201'


group by [DATE entered],DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]), DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]),DATEPART(dd, [DATE entered]), a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate,c.npi,e.npib,c.practiceaddress1 ,c.practiceaddress2,
    b.[Active Inactive]


)

select * from cte_biggie
```

** how do I return the daily `CountAccns` count instead of the monthly?**

I believe that the main issue is with my GROUP BY, but I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: I don't really understand how you can have a monthly total when you are grouping by DATEPART(dd, [Date Entered]) so can't help you there, but can offer some general advise - the DATENAME Function can be used instead of your case statements to get the month/day as a string: LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), 3) = 'jan' : Also if you are still in development phase consider an overhaul of your database structure. Just because you can put spaces in column names, does not mean you should! Lastly I don't understand why you are using a CTE, then performing a single select from it?

Comment: @GarethD thank you so much for your valuable advice. i will update this with your advice

Comment: @GarethD im sorry i want the DAILY not monthly

Comment: any other help would me most appreciated, im very stuck on the GROU PBY i think that is my main problem

Comment: I don't understand how the query can be returning a monthly count, do you mean the count on each row is for one month, or each time you execute the query it is returning a full month's worth of data?

Comment: @GarethD actually im sorry, it is just returning garbage. it is DEFINITELY not returning data per day. every row of data is for 1 day.

Comment: I still don't understand what data you are trying to retrieve. Can you post a demo table, or at least advise what fields you need in the output. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7259/discussion-between-i-and-garethd)

Comment: There's a different statement waiting to get out, but I don't have enough information to extract it - at minimum, place table aliases (the letters) in front of _all_ columns, please.  And your question _still_ doesn't make sense, especially in light of your last comment - do you want the count per day or not?  Also, unless you're actually doing something with the information, don't split your date apart - leave that for your display code, if at all possible.

Comment: @X-Zero thank you.  i just want the COUNT count(a.[specimen id]) for that specific FULL DATE (from table a) for that specific PRACTICE CODE

Comment: If that's all you need, your query is _way_ oversized - for one thing, you shouldn't need any `JOIN`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain of your data structure but It doesn't seem possible to get what you are after, for instance if records exist for more than one sales rep at the same practice code the only way to show both the sales reps is to have more than one row of data for that practise code...